# C++ static variable initialization inside a template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, static

I noticed quite a strange behavior of static variable initialization in function templates. Consider the following example:

```cpp
MyFile * createFile()
{
    std::cout << "createFile" << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
void test(const T& t)
//void test(T t)
{
    static MyFile *f = createFile();
}

void main()
{
    test("one");
    //test("two");
    test("three");
}
```

As long as `f` in `test` is static, I expected `createFile` to be called only once. However, it is called twice.

Having spent some time playing around with the problem, I noticed that removing const reference from the argument in `test` fixes it. Another interesting thing is that the length of the string passed to the function also affects the initialization: when the length of parameters is equal, static variable is initialized only once, otherwise, a new initialization takes place.

Could somebody explain this? Solutions/workarounds apart from the mentioned ones are very welcome.

Comment: You are instantiating the template with 2 different `T`s, a `char[4]` (`"one"`) and a `char[6]` (`"three"`). Therefore you have 2 new types, both containing an `f`, therefore both of those `f`s must be initialised. Hence `createFile()` is called twice.

Comment: Ok, but why simple template version (without const ref) works?

Comment: Pointer decay (you can't take an array by value). Which is not simple enough to describe in a comment. I'll let someone else describe it in an answer.

Comment: @mentalmushroom: Becuse it creates the same `const char *` instantiation for all literals. The reference is the critical piece in this case that makes the length of the literal part of function type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The literal "one" is a `const char [4]`.

this code:

```
test("one")
```

would ideally like to call `test(const char (&)[4])`

This works for `test(const T&)` (because `const char (&) [4]` can bind to `const char (const&) [4]`).

But it cannot work for `test(T t)` because you can't pass string literals by value. They are passed by reference.

However, `const char[4]` can decay to `const char*`, which can match `template<class T> void func(T t)`.

The proof is in the pudding:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void test_const(const T(&t)[N])
{
    std::cout << __func__ << " for literal " << t << " T is a " << typeid(T).name() << " and N is " << N << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void test_mutable(T &t)
{
    std::cout << __func__ << " for literal " << t << " T is a " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void test_const_ref(const T &t)
{
    std::cout << __func__ << " for literal " << t << " T is a " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void test_copy(T t)
{
    std::cout << __func__ << " for literal " << t << " T is a " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    test_const("one");
    test_const("three");
    test_mutable("one");
    test_mutable("three");
    test_const_ref("one");
    test_const_ref("three");
    test_copy("one");
    test_copy("three");
}
```

example results (clang):

```
test_const for literal one T is a c and N is 4
test_const for literal three T is a c and N is 6
test_mutable for literal one T is a A4_c
test_mutable for literal three T is a A6_c
test_const_ref for literal one T is a A4_c
test_const_ref for literal three T is a A6_c
test_copy for literal one T is a PKc
test_copy for literal three T is a PKc
```

Here is a version with demangled names (will compile on clang and gcc):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cxxabi.h>

std::string demangle(const char* name)
{
    int status = -1;
    // enable c++11 by passing the flag -std=c++11 to g++
    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> res {
        abi::__cxa_demangle(name, NULL, NULL, &status),
        std::free
    };

    return (status==0) ? res.get() : name ;
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void test_const(const T(&t)[N])
{
    std::cout << __func__ << " for literal " << t << " T is a " << demangle(typeid(T).name()) << " and N is " << N << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void test_mutable(T &t)
{
    std::cout << __func__ << " for literal " << t << " T is a " << demangle(typeid(T).name()) << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void test_const_ref(const T &t)
{
    std::cout << __func__ << " for literal " << t << " T is a " << demangle(typeid(T).name()) << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void test_copy(T t)
{
    std::cout << __func__ << " for literal " << t << " T is a " << demangle(typeid(T).name()) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    test_const("one");
    test_const("three");
    test_mutable("one");
    test_mutable("three");
    test_const_ref("one");
    test_const_ref("three");
    test_copy("one");
    test_copy("three");
}
```

expected output:

```
test_const for literal one T is a char and N is 4
test_const for literal three T is a char and N is 6
test_mutable for literal one T is a char [4]
test_mutable for literal three T is a char [6]
test_const_ref for literal one T is a char [4]
test_const_ref for literal three T is a char [6]
test_copy for literal one T is a char const*
test_copy for literal three T is a char const*
```

Comment: @Quentin it cant' deduce that. That would make the argument `const const char &`

Comment: Woops, let me try again. It deduces `const char[4]` for `T` :)

Comment: @Quentin the leading const prevents it. It would be `const const char[4]` which is not legal

Comment: Apparently... [It's `char[4]`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4cac65d2c158d2ce). I'm stumped. (edit: the order of `const T` does not change anything)

Comment: But, but, but.  You argue `test(const T&)` will match `const char *` - and thus the static will be constructed once ... but `test(T&)` will match `const char[N]`, and thus the static will be constructed twice.  The issue is that the OP reports the opposite.

Comment: @MartinBonner I gather OP means `test(T)`, not `test(T&)`.

Comment: @bolov. you're right. I've introduced a reference where I should not have. see test code.

Comment: @Quentin fixed the narrative.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to @RichardHodges's answer that explains why different instanciations are used, it is easy to force only one, because arrays can decay to pointer with an explicit template instanciation:

```
test<const char *>("one");
test<const char *>("two");
test<const char *>("three");
```

result in one single call of `createFile`.

In fact (as said in comment by BoBTFish), that is exactly what happens when you write:

```
template <typename T>
void test(const T t)
```

Whatever the size of the array, the array automatically decays to a `const char *` because C++ does not allow to assign directly arrays.

BTW, `void main()` is *bad*. Always use `int main()` and an explicit return.